# Buying Monero Privately in Toronto Canada

Tags: privacy

I would like to buy Monero PRIVATELY in Toronto Canada. I am new to Monero and would love to buy it privately without having to give up my personal info to an exchange to buy it.  Can you please let me know of a place I can go to to buy it privately?

Answer (score 1):

Popular places to buy without KYC are Bisq and LocalMonero.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be stuck with buying Bitcoin (anonymously at a Bitcoin ATM) and changing it for XMR at a site that doesn't require id verification for trading cryptocurrencies, such as coinex.com.

Comment: ...and as it turns out with some digging, there are ATMs in Toronto that will sell you XMR for cash. You pay a premium, as you do at a Bitcoin ATM, but it works.